# Prime ng message (<p-toast>) is covered by modal window(<p-dialog>)

Tags: angular, primeng, toast

I have the following code in Angular:

```
<div>
<p-toast  key="refaLivaImpresion" [baseZIndex]="99999" styleClass="custom-toast"></p-toast>

<p-dialog [(visible)]="imprimirDialog" [style]="{width: '1200px'}" header="Orden de Refacturación LIVEN Impresion"
    [modal]="true" class="p-fluid" [closable]="false" [baseZIndex]="10000">

    <!-- <p-toast  key="refaLivaImpresion" [baseZIndex]="99999" styleClass="custom-toast"></p-toast> -->
 
</p-dialog>
```

- My component.ts is like that:

  ```
   abrirVentanaImprimir(idDocLivenEle:any){
       this.imprimirDialog = true;
       this.messageService.add({ key: 'refaLivaImpresion', severity: 'success', summary: 'Se genero la solicitud satisfactoriamente', life: 10000  });
       this.refaVentasBusquedaService.obtenerDetalleImpresion(idDocLivenEle)
       .subscribe((res :any)=> {
           console.log("obtenerDetalleDeNotas " +  res);

           if (Object.keys(res).length > 0){

               this.miArrayImprimir = res;
           }

       },
       (error :any)=>{
           this.messageService.add({ severity: 'error', summary: 'Ocurrió un error al ejecutar el registro', detail: error.error.mensaje });
       });
  ```

  }
- This function is triggered after an http request is successful which triggers the modal (p-dialog) through the variable 'imprimirDialog = true', additionally passing this should show me the message toast saying that everything was successful.
- What happens is that the notification message appears but it is covered by the popup modal window, I tried setting a 'baseZIndex' lower than the modal and higher than the  but I still can't get the toast to display above the modal.

Note: If I put the  inside the  tag this works, but the toast is shown in the upper right corner but of the modal but not of the screen itself, what I want is to show the toast to the upper right corner of the screen, I would appreciate some help on some point that maybe I'm making a mistake.